# replaceAll with Regex not replacing full result

Tags: java, android, regex

```
String myString = "
Opt. 1. FOO BAR
Opt. 2. FOO2 BAR2"


myString.replaceAll("([A-Z])\\w+. [0-9].", "<b>$1</b>")
```

its returning:

```
<b>O</b> FOO BAR
```

and

```
<b>O</b> FOO2 BAR2
```

but i want

```
<b>Opt 1.</b> FOO BAR ...
```

why its no returning the full replaced text with ?
if i use $2 i get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4`

Comment: `$1` refers to everything in the first group, so do `([A-Z]\\w+ [0-9].)` to include more than just the first letter.

Comment: not working if i do this, it doesnt even replace, still the text normally =(

Comment: ohhh thank you, i forgot to put EVERYTHING between () ! can you add as answer so i can mark it? just one add to your answer, i need to put [A-Za-z]

Answer (score 0):

Your first capture group: `([A-Z])` only captures the first capital character of the string. If your string always begins with `Opt.` then a number, try this pattern ([stub](https://regex101.com/r/mO9dD8/1)):

```
^(Opt\.\s+\d+\.)
```